# How to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 on Ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using the following commands to install `wkhtmltopdf` but it's not working and given same notification on browser.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecometrica/servers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: what notification is it giving?

Comment: Report
Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. The report will be shown in html.

wkhtmltopdf.org

Comment: try [this](http://webkul.com/blog/odoo-wkhtmltopdf-upgrade-version/).

Comment: I got this error when enter the command
sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopdf/files/archive/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
--2016-01-27 00:48:07--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopdf/files/archive/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.60
Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-01-27 00:48:07 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 9):

To install `wkhtmltopdf` in Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Install `xvfb` server:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xvfb
   ```
2. Download the `deb` from the  `wkhtmltopdf` [download page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

   For Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit:

   ```
   wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Install `wkhtmltopdf`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Install dependencies (if needed):

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

Comment: showing error at step3 
dpkg: error processing archive wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_i386.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_i386.deb

tried with Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) amd64 / i386  from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: @praaveen Looks like you need an armhf binary, *not* i386. Try the "raspbian" package from the download page.